# Identify entries in one list that appear in a different form in another list

Tags: excel, compare, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have two lists of names and would like to highlight the cells with surnames in List 1 that are present in List 2. The problem is I may need this list of duplicates to include wildcards.

List 1 contains names in the format:

```
W. Viitala
T. Saarinen
I. Äijälä
```

List 2 just contains:

```
Viitala
Saarinen
Äijälä
```

Also, this may need to include having some sort of function that removes foreign characters, eg: Äijälä to Aijala as they might sometimes be included in list 2?

Is this possible?

Also, is it possible to automate the process of removing commas and replacing them with new lines? So that the following names could be pasted in but each in a new row?

Viitala, Saarinen, Äijälä

*Edit not from OP but from one of OP's comments* Link to example:

http://gyazo.com/9bec82c67b76f6073491f53580945de4

Comment: It all sounds very possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well the conditional formatting > duplicate values obviously only compares exact matches, id need something like that but with wildcards.

ive tried examples ive found online of using "match" and "countif" but struggled to get anywhere

Comment: I would say "(i) how to use wildcards in a search for duplicates", is the most important for now, thanks.

Comment: I am looking to identify names in list 2 that appear as surnames in list 1. The wildcard idea was just because list one has the names in the format of "first initial. surname" where as list 2 is just surnames.

List 2 format can vary, It may sometimes be a combination of "first name surname", dot space, or just last name, so really the wild card needs to find the surname

Comment: That seems to just display the row number that it finds the name in list 1. Ideally id like it to be a conditional format, highlighting the names in list 1 that appear in list 2

Comment: Sorry pnuts, where do you mean? I am yet to find a working solution

Comment: That is working, thank you! Do you want to submit it as an answer and i'll ok it?

Answer (score 0):

I have done that, using VBA. I didn´t find a way to compare 1 Cell to a column.

Do you know how to use VBA?
There is this function: InStr(start position, string1, string2)

Sub findDuplicated()

```
For i = 2 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row      'values to be highlighted
    For j = 2 To Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row  'strings to be searched
       If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, Cells(j, 7).Value) <> 0 Then      ' if it is found
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)             ' highlight list1
            Cells(j, 7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)             ' highlight list2
       End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

It will search at column A if any of column B values exist there. It they match, it will highlight the found match at column A.
Is it what you want?

Besides, you can remove characters using. You will need to call this function for each character you want to replace:

```
Sub commaToDot(char1,char2)
    Range("B1:B50").Select           ' here you select your range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, char1, char2)       ' it replaces char1 for char2
    Next
End sub
```

Comment: I have pressed, alt + F11 and pasted that code in to a new module and ran the macro (not experienced with this at all). The values it has highlighted appear to be completely random. For example, i have added "test" in both lists and it isnt highlighted, as you can see here: http://gyazo.com/6436f4083c8afba8b47acdee0c69177d

Comment: hehe I can see why... Where it is written Cells(i,1) this 1 means what column we are using... I will edit this code to fit your document. Gimme 2 min

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full proof solution but might help:
Assuming List1 in A1:A10 and List2 in B1:B10

Apply conditional formatting in B1:B10
- New rule
- Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Write this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$A10;"*" & B1 & "*")>0
```

Comment: This just appears to spring up an error, this looks similar to something i saw online that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Ok this works, if i add it to a column next to list 2 it displays true or false. Can i use this as conditional formatting?

I've tried for list 1, adding a conditional format of:

'=COUNTIF(A:A,"*" & G:G & "*")>0'

but it doesnt work

Comment: Yeah, in my country argument separator is the ";" change to ","...
It is the idea I tried it with conditional formatting and it works, if  you want to apply to G1:G10 with list 1 in A1:A10
- select G1:G10
- conditional formatting
- write this formula: =COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,"*" & G1 & "*")>0

Comment: I am getting completely lost here i'm afraid. What i want to do is highlight the names in the cells in A:A that also appear in list 2 in G:G. Here's a screenshot to show you what i am doing, but it's not working http://gyazo.com/9bec82c67b76f6073491f53580945de4

Comment: OK, so in that case try this:
   =COUNTIF($G$1:$G$13,"*" & RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-2) & "*")>0

Comment: or -3, you have a space in the 3º position

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting with a rule such as:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),G:G,0))
```

applied to A:A appears to suit the OP.

Comment: Ah, it appears i need more reputation to vote this up. Thank you very much anyway

Comment: In the event of there being more than one person of the same last name eg: P. Degen and D. Degen, it doesn't seem to highlight them. Do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: edit: it appears to only work now if there is a first name or a dot etc... in front of the surname as shown here, ive had to put a dot then space in front of names http://gyazo.com/3cf6a26fe0797a959a9d8a6a232c9626

Comment: The source data for the first few tests did, only come across this now, all part of the testing process i guess!